# Magento 2 : How to clear cache using REST?

Tags: magento2, api, cache, rest-api, log-cleaning

How can I clear the Magento 2 page cache using REST API after updating the product quantity from 0 to 10?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is no way to do it directly. Check the swagger and you 'll see it. However, there are other actions that can trigger cache refresh, for example, creating a category. I am not sure. It is only an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago, I wrote this module https://github.com/tevtex/module-cachemanagement
You can enable/disable/clean/flush caches using API.

You can find the installation instructions on the github.